# How to get mutual friends on facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, mutual-friendship

I was searching for any way to get the mutual friends on facebook and i got this one

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fmutualfriends%2F&version=v2.0

But i found out that it is deprecated !! although Tinder got shared friends on Facebook.

So is there any way that i can get mutual friends on facebook  on my iOS app?

Comment: How did you end up solving this? I have the same issue and I would love to know.

Comment: @meisel Facebook deprecated it, even for apps that already have this feature , Facebook only gave them one year and then it will give them error. But if you already have the facebook friends list , I made a server function to get the common ids between  the two friends'list. Hope this help

Comment: Im interested in your server function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since API v2.0, you (after granting `user_friends` permission) can only get the list of mutual friends with a user that also granted `user_friends` permission. The list will only have mutual friends **that are using your app and granted `user_friends` permissions**.

Please, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user.context/mutual_friends

Cheers!

Update: The All Mutual Friends API feature was deprecated for Graph API v3.1 on July 26, 2018, and will be deprecated for all versions on October 24, 2018.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-ALL_MUTUAL_FRIENDS

Comment: Thanks , I had to make a twist to get the mutual friends , I got the friends Ids of the two users , and the common IDs ,are the common friends.then i get their data by the their IDs

Comment: I wish Facebook's documentation made it as clear as this! Cheers